# Repeater Textbox Validation Using Button Event in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, repeater

I have this repeater where i have added some validation to a textbox. However, the button I wish to use to fire the validation is outside the repeater. Is this possible? If so, I'd rather use server side.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptCart" runat="server" onitemcommand="Cart_ItemCommand" onitemdatabound="Cart_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="cartQty" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("shoppingCartQty")%>'></asp:TextBox></span>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="oops!" ControlToValidate="cartQty" CssClass="errortxt" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator><asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="oops!" ValidationExpression="^[0-9]*[1-9]+[0-9]*$" CssClass="errortxt" ControlToValidate="cartQty" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator></span>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

<asp:LinkButton ID="cartRecalcButton" CssClass="cartrecalcbutton" 
    runat="server" ToolTip="recalculate your shopping cart" 
    onclick="cartRecalcButton_Click">&nbsp;
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: if you want to validate the things in server side, then there is no need to use `FieldValidator` control. add a span tag with an ID to your markup that runs on server, then change it's `InnerHtml` in your `Button_Click` event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. If you don't want the clientside validation to happen you can set the [BaseValidator.EnableClientScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.enableclientscript%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) property to false. Validaton controls always performs validation on the server.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have any problems using a button outside of the repeater to validate data in the repeater. You can use a `ValidationGroup` if you want to limit the scope of the validation to the repeater.